# What does em dash mean here?

Tags: punctuation

*These days I am studying about the different uses of em dash.
What is the use of "em dash" here?*

> The color pink has been my favourite. I have developed a passion for
>   this beautiful color. I like pink so much that I’ve had my bedroom
>   painted pink. This has had a really soothing effect on me—it’s made me
>   more relaxed.

Is the following equivalent with the sentence with em dash?

**This has had a really soothing effect on me and it’s made me more relaxed.**

Answer (score 2):

The dash here is equivalent to a colon, and it's also not much different from having a full stop, but obviously the dash makes clear that the two sentences are linked, which a full stop wouldn't.  There is no particular reason to imagine an "and".  In fact, adding the "and" makes the two thoughts sound a bit less connected.  The way I read it, the relaxation exemplifies the soothing effect, whereas the "and" would perhaps make them sound like two separate effects.